# Second Executable Without Instrumentation Libraries

Tags: c#, .net

My application collects data from an instrument and saves it to a database.  The application can also view previously collected data.

I would like a second executable for only loading old data which does not include the data acquisition component (and therefore would not require the instrument libraries).  It would just be a subset of the full application ("Collect Data" button disabled).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use [`#define`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx), or a parameter to the current application to set button property. You can copy application and manually exclude unused libraries (if there are many). You could make this a configuration variable and store it in app.config. A few choices really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make separate projects ?

- Instrumentation : types representing captured data (class library project)
- Instrumentation.Capture : methods/object that do capture data (class library project)
- YourCaptureApplication : your big app that does everything
- YourUtilityApplication : does a subset of what your big app does

Project dependencies :

- Instrumentation.Capture references Instrumentation
- YourCaptureApplication references Instrumentation.Capture
- YourUtilityApplication references Instrumentation

Also, it's probably wise to implement de-/serialization of your data in Instrumentation, doing so will allow your utility to only references the core classes.

I've used the prefix Instrumentation but that's just an example.